# Trigger an event from within a function

Tags: reactjs

How can I trigger an event within a function? In the example below when `componentDidUpdate` fires the `this.testHandle()` fires but the `this.handleFilterByClass()` doesn't fire at all. I assume this has something to do with the event. What am I missing?

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevProps.studentUserProfiles.length !== this.props.studentUserProfiles.length) {
    this.handleFilterByClass();
    this.testHandle();
  }
}

testHandle() {
  console.log('testHandle');
}
handleFilterByClass = classId => (event) => {
  console.log(111);
}
```

Comment: Your `handleFilterByClass` is returning a function. Try to write `this.handleFilterByClass()();` as an experiment.

Comment: change `handleFilterByClass = classId => (event) => {` to `handleFilterByClass: classId => (event) => {`

Comment: that appears to error @dysfunc

Comment: @dysfunc this errors too. ` handleFilterByClass: classId => (event) => {`

Comment: i think you're looking for this ` handleFilterByClass(classId){ console.log(classId) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a function from `handleFilterByClass`. Remove `(event) =>` if you want to be able to invoke it directly.

```
handleFilterByClass = classId => {
  console.log(111);
}
```

Comment: I get this error. ` Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.`

Comment: @bp123 That's not related to your question. Consider creating another question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we can help you.